# Python Selenium driver.find_element_by_xpath can't find element within iframe

Tags: python, html, selenium, iframe

I'm trying to crawl a website for sports statistics, and realised all of the important data is inside an iframe. I use driver.switch_to.frame() to switch to the iframe and that doesn't throw any errors.

```
frame1 = '//iframe[@src="reallylongsource"]'


 driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath(frame1))
```

But then when I try to access the information inside the iframe,

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .//div[@class="classname"]
```

is raised. I can see that the element is there in the HTML but I can't find it with selenium. I've tried locating it with CSS selector as well with no success.

I'm quite sure it's the correct iframe as well. I've tried finding it both with the xpath and by tag name and they were the same iframe.

When I print

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath(frame1).text)
```

I only get blank space

I've been butting my head against the wall for quite a while now and can't figure it out!

It seems like I'm able to switch to the correct iframe, but selenium can't find any information within it.

Comment: Check inspect element console from your browser with this `document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;` where `iframe_id` is your id to check if you get the content.

Comment: can you share the link where that iframe lives?
is there more than 1 iframe on the page?if not, just try to find by drive.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))

Comment: @Xitrex, seemslike something with selectors..

Comment: Don't use a . it's only for child xpaths.

Comment: Here is the link to the page: 
https://campobet.se/en/sport/prelive?sportids=66 
My goal is to be able to select a game and continue to the page where the bets are listed and collect the info about the odds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe'))

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="classname"]')

driver.quit()
```

if it's the same what you're doing in your code, please provide more info to take a look of the page

try this, it will move to the first game of first type game and get all of the scores and prints it:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://campobet.se/en/sport/prelive?sportids=66')
time.sleep(5)

driver.switch_to.frame(
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'https://sb1client-altenar.biahosted.com')]"))
time.sleep(1)

game_types = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@name='leagues-selector']")
time.sleep(1)
game_types[0].click()
time.sleep(1)
games = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    "//div[@class='_asb_simple-button _asb_simple-button-pointer  _asb_leagues-selector-item ']")
games[0].click()
time.sleep(1)
scores = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='asb-flex-cc asb-unshrink _asb_price-block-content-price ']/span")
time.sleep(1)

scores_values = [el.text for el in scores]
time.sleep(1)
print(scores_values)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's pretty much exactely what I'm doing. Heres the link to the page:
 campobet.se/en/sport/prelive?sportids=66
 My goal is to be able to select a game, go to its page and collect information about all the available odds for my friend who's in to E-sport betting

Comment: Thank you, yeah that part was poorly written by me. I only want help on how to access the information inside the iframe so that my code can process it. The rest I want to figure out myself!

Comment: It seems I'm able to switch to the right iframe but selenium doesn't seem to be able to find any information within it. My question is why this is, or how can I help my code locate what I'm looking for within the iframe.

Comment: @Xitrex give me a sec, I will post the solution

Comment: @Xitrex check it out

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't home. But yes! That worked! Is it because you used find_elements instead of find_element?

Comment: Either way, thanks alot! That really helped. Hopefully I'll manage to figure everything out now that I have a functioning solution to work from!